# How long can a man stay away from sinful activities?

Tags: nikah, sex

As we know, men are more eager than female to have sex. Men sexually arouse very quickly. How can he control his desire as his searching for a bride for long time and couldn't get proper (pious,polite etc) bride for him. As women can control themselves for only 4-6 months from any sinful activities.
So, Is there any time limit for men to control his desire.

Comment: You have a lot to learn about women.  Sexually,  they're not much different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking if a person is addicted to sinful activities like masturbation etc. how long can he stay without repeating it?

First thing I wish to present is this, don't worry Allah will help you, if you strive sincerely,

> *"Three groups of people Allah obliged Himself to help them: Mujahid in the cause of Allah, a worker to pay his debt, and the one who wants to marry to live a chaste life." (Tirmidhi 1661, Nisai 3120, Ibn e Majah 2518, Ahmed 9637)*

Next, you need to stay from **triggers** which lead you to those activities. In simple sense, you just need to do all those things which addicts do in their rehab course, *stay away from triggers, get new experiences*.

Where is it written that women can stay only upto 4-6 months? Didn't the wives of Prophets stay chaste for the rest of their lives after Prophet was gone?

Answer (score 0):

No fixed time limit! How long men or women can control their desires depends on a myriad of factors! From genetics and humoral makeup, to food intake, to surrounding culture, the amount of interaction with opposite sex, mental occupations, etc.

But ideally a Muslim man that has developed some degree of will-power, self-control and psychic strength due to Islamic self-discipline and principled conduct may be able to abstain even indefinitely from sexual activities. I personally know many single religious men and even boys who stay clean for years because of their maximum commitment to Islamic instructions on chastity.

Answer (score -1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Abdullah (b. Mas'ud) (Allah be pleased with him) reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said to us:

**0 young men, those among you who can support a wife should marry, for it restrains eyes (from casting evil glances) and preserves one from immorality; but he who cannot afford It should observe fast for it is a means of controlling the sexual desire.**(Sahih Muslim)

One should not delay his marriage when he knows that its becoming difficult for him to control his sexual desires so he could prevent himself from Zina of any kind.With the help of fasting he could control his sexual desires as said by Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him.

Not sure the time limit for men and how you got the calculated time period for controlling desires of women if you could specify this.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best.